How to like/react on a linkedIn post using linkedIn shared APIs ? #linkedIn
I am trying to integrate the linkedIn APIs in the system. I want to like the post from my behalf. which API should i use to like/react on post?

I got solution myself ... Refer this document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/reactions-api?view=li-lms-2024-05&tabs=http#reactions-1

Also you would be needing w_member_social in your application
